# Problema con Array en Java

Tags: java, array

estamos haciendo una guía para mejorar nuestro pensamiento lógico en la facultad, pero realmente no entiendo como poder hacer este ejercicio. Estuve 2 horas tratando y no logro sacarlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo había pensado anidar unos ciclos for e ir preguntando si el carácter de la iteración "i" es igual al carácter de la iteración del ciclo anidado ("j"), que lo guarde en un array nuevo, y posteriormente que lo muestre por consola. Pero esta solución, implica que siempre lo guarde si encuentra uno igual, entonces nunca va a mostrar la palabra "inmet" sino algo parecido a esto: "IINNNNMMMIIIIINNNNEEEEENNNNTTTTEE"

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arrayPrueba = new char[] { 'I', 'N', 'M', 'I', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'T', 'E' };

    mostrarSinRepetidos(arrayPrueba);
}

public static void mostrarSinRepetidos(char[] elementos) {
    char[] devolucion = new char[elementos.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < elementos.length; j++) {
            if (elementos[i] == elementos[j]) {
                System.out.print(elementos[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    for (char c : devolucion) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden ayudar a entender, y no solo darme la solución, se los agradecería un monton

Answer (score 1):

L a solución es bastante sencilla y no necesitas anidar ciclos `for`. Sin embargo, hacer preguntas de clarificación a tus profesores te ayudará también a entender como resolver el problema. Algunas preguntas son:

1. ¿Puede haber símbolos en el texto?
2. ¿Puede haber mayúsculas y minúsculas?

Hay dos soluciones muy simples para este problema. Una usando una estructura de datos del tipo `hash`, pero si aún no has visto ese tipo de estructuras, un arreglo auxiliar puede ayudar.

Todos los `char` pueden ser convertidos a un entero. Estos elementos tendrán un valor de entre 0 y 127.
Te recomiendo ver la tabla de ASCII para entender mejor esto: https://theasciicode.com.ar

Teniendo esto en cuenta, una forma de resolver el problema es crear un arreglo de `boolean` con un tamaño de `128`. El arreglo tiene inicializado todos sus elementos a `false`.

Por ejemplo, si tienes la letra `a`, su valor en `int` es el `97`. Por lo tanto, en tu arreglo de `boolean`, marcarás dicho indice como `true`, indicando que la letra `a` ya apareció y así poder ignorarla cuando vuela a salir.

Te dejó la solución usando el arreglo de `boolean` y la solución usando un `Set`.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] arrayPrueba = new char[] { 'I', 'N', 'M', 'I', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'T', 'E' };
        mostrarSinRepetidosUsinArray(arrayPrueba);
        mostrarSinRepetirUsingHash(arrayPrueba);
    }

    public static void mostrarSinRepetidosUsinArray(char[] word) {
        // Crear arreglo de bool de 128
        boolean[] repetido = new boolean[128];
        for (int i = 0; i < repetido.length; i++)
            repetido[i] = false; 

        // Todos los char pueden convertiste a int.
        // En ASCII, los caracteres solo van del 0 al 127 de ahí el arreglo de 128.
         
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : word) {
            int charIntValue = (int)c;
            // Verificamos si el carácter ya aparecio alguna vez.
            if (repetido[charIntValue])
                continue;

            sb.append(c);
            // Marcamos el elemento como que ya apreció, así no lo consideramos
            // cuando vuelva a aparecer.
            repetido[charIntValue] = true;
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    public static void mostrarSinRepetirUsingHash(char[] word) {
        HashSet<Character> hs = new HashSet<Character>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (char c : word) {
            if (hs.contains(c))
                continue;

            sb.append(c);
            // Añadimos el carácter a la lista de carácteres que han salido.
            hs.add(c);
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo sería crear un array que guarde los elementos únicos, e ir verificando contra ese array si el carácter existe, para incluirlo si no es así. El problema es que en Java los arrays primitivos **tienen que ser declarados con un tamaño fijo**, pero tú no sabes, al momento de crear el array, cuántos elementos tendrá.

Para este tipo de cosas existen objetos más flexibles: `List`, `ArrayList`, `HashMap`. Con cualquiera de ellos podrás lograr fácilmente lo que quieres. Sin ellos, tendrás que pasar por procedimientos oscuros para lograrlo.

Veamos un ejemplo basado en `List`:

```
public static void mostrarSinRepetidos(char[] elementos) 
{
    //Guardará los caracteres únicos
    List<Character> uniqueChars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) 
    {
        /*
            Verificamos mediante el método contains
            en negativo ! si el carácter no está
            en uniqueChars, si no está lo agregagmos
        */
        if(!uniqueChars.contains(elementos[i]))
        {
            uniqueChars.add(elementos[i]);
        }
    }
    //Prueba de impresión, esto es Java 8+
    uniqueChars.forEach(System.out::print); 
}
```

**Salida:**

```
INMET
```

#### Post-Data

Cabe decir que, desde Java 8, con la API Stream, todas estas tareas se facilitan de un modo asombroso.

El código anterior se reduciría a esto:

```
Stream<Character> uniqueChars = CharBuffer.wrap(elementos).chars().distinct().mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch);

//Prueba de impresión
uniqueChars.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: Usar un `ArrayList` no es muy eficiente. Una estructura hash tiene una complejidad de O(1) vs una lista que para verificar si algo existe o no, tiene una complejidad de O(n). No hay procedimientos “oscuros” si se tiene claridad del rango de los caracteres.